# Procura de matriz dentro de outra matriz em Js

Tags: javascript, array, matriz

Gostaria de saber se é possível identificar se uma matriz está dentro de outra matriz em javascript.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, se a matriz A está dentro de B ou C dentro de A.

Estou tentando aplicar o seguinte código:

```
a = [[1,2],[5,4]]

c = [[2,4],[10,8], [1, 2], [5,4]]

function compare(first, last)
{
    var result = first.filter(function(item){ return last.indexOf(item) > -1});   
    return result.length;  
}    

console.log(compare(a, c) === a.length);
```

Comment: Nesse caso você quer comparar se duas matrizes são iguais, não? Apesar de que seu código não reflete a imagem. Cadê a matriz B no código?

Comment: no caso que fiz nao teria B, mas A está dentro de C

Comment: Nesse caso então você quer retornar um booleano (verdadeiro ou false) de acordo com a pesquisa "`a` está dentro de `c`"?

Comment: isso mesmo, seria essa a resposta